# "undefined reference" no construtor de uma funcao C++

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, construtor

Estou criando uma classe de nome VS1838B que e composta por outras instâncias.

Esse e o header da classe:

```
#ifndef INFRAREDRECEIVERVS1838B_H
#define INFRAREDRECEIVERVS1838B_H

#include "Arduino.h"
#include "IRremote.h"
#include "IRremoteInt.h"

class VS1838B{

public:
    //Construtor
    VS1838B(int pinoReceptorIR);

    //Atributos
    IRrecv _receptorIR;                   //Objeto do tipo IRrecv
    decode_results _bufferSinalRecebido;  //Objeto que armazena o sinal recebido
    int _pinoInput;

};


#endif  /* INFRAREDRECEIVERVS1838B_H */
```

Esse e o arquivo .cpp

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "InfraRedReceiverVs1838b.h"
#include "IRremote.h"
#include "IRremoteInt.h"


//Construtor
VS1838B::VS1838B(int pinoReceptorIR)
:_receptorIR (pinoReceptorIR), _bufferSinalRecebido()
{
_pinoInput = 11;
}
```

Obtenho a seguinte mensagem de erro ao tentar instanciar a classe.

InfraRedReceiverVs1838b.cpp:9: undefined reference to `IRrecv::IRrecv(int)'

Esse e o header da classe a qual nao foi encontrada referencia:

```
// main class for receiving IR
class IRrecv
{
public:
  IRrecv(int recvpin);
  void blink13(int blinkflag);
  int decode(decode_results *results);
  void enableIRIn();
  void resume();
private:
  // These are called by decode
  int getRClevel(decode_results *results, int *offset, int *used, int t1);
  long decodeNEC(decode_results *results);
  long decodeSony(decode_results *results);
  long decodeSanyo(decode_results *results);
  long decodeMitsubishi(decode_results *results);
  long decodeRC5(decode_results *results);
  long decodeRC6(decode_results *results);
  long decodePanasonic(decode_results *results);
  long decodeLG(decode_results *results);
  long decodeJVC(decode_results *results);
  long decodeSAMSUNG(decode_results *results);
  long decodeHash(decode_results *results);
  int compare(unsigned int oldval, unsigned int newval);

} 
;
```

Por que a mensagem de erro? Como consigo construir um classe que tenha como atributos instância de outras classes? Sou iniciante e qualquer ajuda e bem vinda.

Comment: A definição da classe `IRrecv` tá em qual arquivo de cabeçalho (.h)? Ele foi incluido no cabeçalho (.h) da classe `VS1838B`?

Comment: A classe IRrecv esta no mesmo arquvio do IRremote.h

Comment: Você tem certeza que está linkando no executável final o arquivo obj que contém a definição do construtor?

Comment: O problema ocorre no momento de ligação da sua biblioteca ou executável. A biblioteca ou objeto que implementa o construtor da classe `IRrecv` não está sendo ligado ao seu binário final e isso deve ser resolvido configurando o seu projeto na IDE utilizada. Caso a classe `IRrecv` foi feita por você mesmo o que falta é implementar o construtor.

Answer (score -1):

Experimenta utilizar:

Na definição da classe declara:

```
IRrecv* _receptorIR;                   //Objeto do tipo IRrecv
decode_results* _bufferSinalRecebido;  //Objeto que armazena o sinal recebido
```

E colocar o construtor desta forma:

```
//Construtor
VS1838B::VS1838B(int pinoReceptorIR)
{
    _pinoInput = 11;
    _receptorIR = new IRrecv(pinoReceptorIR);
    _bufferSinalRecebido = new decode_results();
}
```

Não esqueça de criar o destrutor e liberar as devidas memórias.